# Turn off reflection

Tags: reflection

How can I turn off the reflection to make some corrections to the house[image]

Comment: Please be so kind to post different questions for different problems. On this site it is favored to have one issue per question. This way others can get help for specific similar problems without having to read through everything to find the part they are actually looking for. And we can provide more information per problem. And ask for more details for clarification, because without knowing how your scene is set up, your objects are built and what exactly you have done with them, each of your questions can have multiple solutions or different ways of solving them depending on your goals.

Comment: Hi, Beetle.. welcome..2 things... 1: please split this question up, as Gordon has suggested. 2: We have no idea what 'the' house is, or 'the'  windows are, and that matters. So please illustrate your specific case. You can embed images into a post using the tools provided. Sharing a representative .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/ is the surest way to avoid misunderstandings. Please edit, and we can re-open.

Comment: Hello Gordon, hopefully I edited my question correctly. This page is not like a regular email its a lot going on this page and I hope its right

Comment: Hello, @BettleBug.. thanks for the illustration. We've re-opened, but you could still clarify a little more, please. What problem are you experiencing, that you want to solve? Is there a reason you can't edit your model in 'Solid' view, with no texture at all? There may well be, but we need to know what it is, I think, to help you set up the editing environment you want.

Comment: Hello Gordon, when I tried to combine the house so I can move it the reflection in the window got distorted. I wanted to know how to turn off the reflection in the glass so once I get the answer to combining the house I will not have that problem.